# why one of the parameter is of containing type in operator overloading

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

My question is why it is compulsory to have one of the containing class object as parameter in operator overloading what is the reason behind to have one parameter like this?

Comment: i didn't find the correct answer to me that is the reason why i am posting if any one has the answer please post me the link

Comment: Please include some code so we know what you are asking about.

Answer (score 0):

You are overloading the operator for a particular class/struct which implies that at least one of the operands must be of the same type - the operands are defined by the parameters.

It's easier if you think of how you would use the overloaded operator, particularly with a unary operator such as ++. Obviously, in order to call your overloaded ++ you must apply it to a class of the type in which you overloaded it, otherwise how would the compiler know you intended to call your overloaded operator.

Similarly, with a binary operator, the compiler needs to know where the overloaded operator is defined. If you overload the + operator on class A using parameters of class B and C then try to add an instance of B to an instance of C, why would the compiler think you intended to use the overloaded operator on A? What if class B and C also had overloaded + operators?